# Does proper time have two different values or meanings?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames, time-dilation, observers

I'm trying to intuitively understand proper time which is defined as the time that is always measured in a moving observer’s or particle's rest frame and is given by the equation

$\Delta\tau = \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}\Delta t$, where $\Delta t$ is the coordinate time.

My confusion stems from the following, if proper time is the time measured in a moving observer's or a moving particle's rest frame, then shouldn't $v^2 = 0$ in the proper time equation as in the moving observer's or the moving particle's own reference frame it is stationary. Therefore wouldn't the inverse of gamma take on the following form? $\sqrt{1 - \frac{0^2}{c^2}}=1$.

But if this is the case wouldn't this make proper time the same as coordinate time, and if so, why even incorporate the inverse gamma term in the first place if $v^2$ is always $0$ in a moving observer's or moving particle's own rest frame?

But setting $v^2 = 0$ would seem to make even less sense as the time dilation equation is the ratio of proper time to coordinate time

$\Delta t' = \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta t\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$

Therefore, if the velocity term in proper time is set to zero, then the time dilation formula would be meaningless, as it would mean time dilation is just the ratio of coordinate time to coordinate time.

$\Delta t' = \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta t\sqrt{1 - \frac{0^2}{c^2}}}$ $ = \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta t}$

Therefore, its logical to conclude that the velocity term in proper time cannot be zero, but if it's not zero then what velocity gets entered in the proper time equation for $v^2$? Is it the relative velocity between an external observer and the moving observer or particle?

But that doesn't make much sense either as proper time is supposed to be invariant. So how can it be invariant if in the moving observer's or particle's own reference frame $v^2 = 0$, yet to an external observer $v^2 > 0$, or thirdly if another observer measures a different velocity for the moving observer or particle altogether?

So is proper time the time measured in a moving observer's or a moving particle's rest frame, or is it the time of the moving observer or the moving particle (stationary in its own reference frame) as measured by an external observer? Additionally, how can proper time be invariant if $v^2 = 0$ in the moving observer's or particle's reference frame (which would also make the time dilation equation meaningless) but be $v^2 > 0$ as seen by an external observer?

Comment: The equation $\Delta t' = \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta t\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$ is incorrect. The $v$ in the equation is the relative velocity between both frames. Proper time is always the time measured _inside_ a given frame of reference (rest frame), or the time measured by another observer who is stationary (relative velocity is zero) relative to the first. There are many misconceptions here and I would suggest you read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation).

Comment: How is the equation incorrect? Also, what does this mean - "The v
 is the (correct) equation is the relative velocity between". I don't understand that that means.

Comment: You have a $\Delta t$ in the denominator _and_ numerator. Remove the one in the denominator. See the link I provided for more information.

Comment: It's not incorrect, proper time is $\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}\Delta t$, the term $\Delta t$ is supposed to be there, sometimes it's hidden because coordinate time is taken to be 1 but it's always there.

Comment: Then I would suggest you read up on proper time and time dilation again. Time dilation is the ratio proper time to coordinate time. Proper time =$ \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}\Delta t$. This means all of its terms are used in the time dilation formula.

Comment: The equation you have in your last comment for proper time is correct and _that_ $\Delta t$ is the coordinate time. My point is the equation you have above, the one I put in my comment, is not correct. Cheers.

Comment: You are aware right that the time dilation formula is only a ratio of proper time to coordinate time, but it itself (the time dilation formula) is not a coordinate nor a length, so yes, it is dimensionless.

Comment: I never said "_the time dilation formula is only a ratio of proper time to coordinate time, but it itself (the time dilation formula) is not a coordinate nor a length, so yes, it is dimensionless_" whatever that means. What I meant was dividing proper time by coordinate time does give you a dimensionless ratio. Cheers.

Comment: I never stated that you stated "the time dilation formula is only a ratio of proper time to coordinate time, but it itself (the time dilation formula) is not a coordinate nor a length, so yes, it is dimensionless". I'm stating that the time dilation formula is only a dimensionless ratio.  Secondly, "What I meant was dividing proper time by coordinate time does give you a dimensionless ratio" which is exactly what the time dilation formula is - a dimensionless ratio. Glad we're on the same page. Cheers

Comment: Also, your assertion that " The v in the equation is the relative velocity between both frames." makes proper time not invariant as different observers in different reference frames will measure different velocities. Or if you're measuring it within your own rest frame then v is zero, which again reduces proper time down to coordinate time. So, are you certain that it's not you who has the many misconceptions? – Cheers.

Comment: The relative velocity is a value that's always given in a particular problem, and is generally not something either observer needs to measure. Of course, if $v=0$ then $\Delta\tau=\Delta t$ and $\Delta\tau$ _is_ the time measure in a rest frame. This does not mean the other observer suddenly stops moving, so how you conclude that $v=0$ between observers is mysterious. I've been trying to help you as have the others who have left answers, and going by similar comments you have left them, I think your misconceptions are more than with just time dilation/relativity.

Comment: Cont'd: ...If so, and as I suspect, you should ask conceptual questions first before ones that involve calculations. I would suggest questions along the lines of "what does the $v$ in the equation represent exactly?" and "what is exactly the difference between proper and coordinate time?" and so on. This will enhance your understanding of what's happening physically without the need for math. All the best. Cheers.

Comment: That's actually a brilliant idea. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your studies.

Answer (score 2):

A better definition of proper time is the time measured by a clock. Then the clock hypothesis is an actual testable hypothesis.

The formula you used has some limitations. It can be used for an arbitrarily moving clock, but only as described in an inertial frame in flat spacetime. The $v$ is the velocity in the given inertial frame, not the clock’s frame.

For a non-inertial clock there is no inertial frame in which $v=0$. So for a non-inertial clock, your concern does not arise.

For an inertial clock the clock’s velocity is only $v=0$ in its rest frame. In that frame indeed the proper time is equal to the coordinate time along the clock’s worldline.

In any case, the proper time is invariant. It is simply $d\tau=\sqrt{-ds^2}/c$ which is manifestly invariant. Then $$\frac{d\tau}{dt}=\sqrt{ \frac{ c^2 dt^2 -dx^2-dy^2-dz^2}{c^2 dt^2}  } = \sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$$ So $dt\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}=d\tau$ is invariant

Comment: Is proper time invariant because it stems from the spacetime interval, which is also invariant?

Comment: @AnthonySmith yes, that is correct

Comment: So how can proper time be invariant if - "The v
 is the velocity in the given inertial frame, not the clock’s frame." and "For an inertial clock the clock’s velocity is only v=0
 in its rest frame"? As this would cause the proper time equation to produce two different values.

Comment: @AnthonySmith I added some details showing how $dt\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ is invariant. Neither $v$ nor $dt$ are individually invariant. But together they are as shown

Answer (score 1):

Both $\Delta t$ and $\Delta \tau$ are measurements of time interval during an event, or perhaps the time between two events.  Proper time is a measure of an event that starts and stop at the same location for the observer.  The clock used to measure the time interval does not move for the observer.  As that observer sees things, the clock has not moved.

The longer time interval is measured by someone for whom the previously described clock moves at speed $v$.  In this new observer's frame of reference, "start" and "stop" do not happen at the same location.

Comment: So then what value does the velocity term take on in the proper time equation?

Comment: Also you say "Proper time is a measure of an event that starts and stop at the same location for the observer". So which observer, an external observer watching a particle move between two points or an internal observer that is moving with the particle between those two points?

Comment: For an event to start and stop at the same location for an observer, or relative to that observer, the start and stop must be at the same place, literally on top of each other, as measured relative to that observer.  In that observer's frame of reference, they are both at the same point.  You could call that person an internal observer or a person moving with the clock.

Comment: If I ride on a bus from Chicago to Memphis, my frame of reference stays with me.  The bus is still and the road moves.  A clock moving with me measures proper time for events that happen on or with me and the bus.  Chicago is with me and my clock at the beginning of the ride.  Memphis is with me and my clock at the end of the ride.  In my frame of reference, Chicago has moved away from me and Memphis has move to me  at speed v.  For a ground observer, my clock and I have moved at speed v.  That person would time the journey as longer than I would.  For that observer, the bus moved.

Comment: Great, then what would be the correct proper time formula for moving between Chicago to Memphis?

Comment: If time is measured by a person on the ground, then your formula will yield the time as measured by the clock on the bus with v=speed of the bus.  If the observer is in a car following the bus, moving with the bus, then v=0 for the bus as viewed by the car driver.  The car driver's time will be the same as the time for the clock on the bus.  Every frame of reference has its own time measurement for the duration of the trip.  The proper time, the time as measured on the bus, requires v as the speed at which the bus moves relative to the observer.

Comment: Note that with all of these comments, I am assuming that the observers (on and not on the bus) are not accelerating.  When you add in significant acceleration, relationships can get more complex.

Comment: "If time is measured by a person on the ground, then your formula will yield the time as measured by the clock on the bus with v=speed of the bus. If the observer is in a car following the bus, moving with the bus, then v=0 for the bus as viewed by the car driver." So, this means the proper time equation will produce two different values depending on the value of the velocity term. Hence how can proper time be invariant then?

Comment: Proper time is the time measured in the frame of reference where the start and end of an event occur at the same position, from the perspective of an observer in that frame of reference.  The bus is where the trip begins.  Later, the bus is where the trip ends.  The trip begins and ends at the bus.  The frame of reference of the bus or anything moving with the bus is the frame that measures proper time.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to intuitively understand proper time which is defined as
> the time that is always measured in a moving observer’s or particle's
> rest frame...

It is right. It is the time measured by the clock of the observer.

> and is given by the equation
>
> $\Delta\tau = \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}\Delta t$, where $\Delta t$ is
> the coordinate time.

This equation is only a relation between the coordinate time in a given inertial frame $S$ and the proper time of the observer that has a relative velocity $v$ in relation to this inertial frame.

Suppose a row of synchronized clocks in $S$, aligned in the $x$ direction. The observer, that has a relative velocity $v$ in $x$ direction, checks his clock always when passes by each of them. The outcome of that checkings is that his clock is being delayed according to that expression. Or, what is the same, time is passing faster in $S$, and that's why the effect is called time dilation.

Comment: "The outcome of that checkings is that his clock is being delayed according to that expression." If in his own reference frame is velocity is zero, then how can he calculate that his clock is being delayed? Would he not instead measure the row of synchronized clocks as what's running slow, since they are the clocks that would appear to be moving?

Comment: @AnthonySmith He doesn't calculate. He sees the clocks of the row each time he meets them, and compares with his own.  It is the same principle that a ship goes to Alpha-Centauri at high speed. When arriving there, the local clocks, supposed synchronized with Earth's time,  records more time than the ship's clock.

Comment: perhaps an example would help me. If a particle is moving at 0.86 the speed of light ($v = 0.86c$) relative to an external observer, and the external observer measures a time interval of $\Delta t = 10$ seconds, we can calculate the particle's proper time as follows:

$\Delta\tau = \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}\Delta t = \sqrt{1 - \frac{(0.86c)^2}{c^2}}(10\text{ s}) \approx 4.31\text{ s}$

Therefore, the particle would have a measured proper time of approximately 4.31 seconds for the same time interval that the external observer measures as 10 seconds. Is that not, correct?

Comment: No. You can only use this formula for the particle (proper time) and the external frame (not a single external observer), full of synchronized clocks (coordinate time). Besides this remark, there is a miscalculation.

Comment: Ok, so then what is the correct formula and what is the miscalculation?